# Markov's Lemma modified

Tags: probability-theory, proof-writing

I'm trying to give a proof to a formula found on my professor's notes.
It states that

> Given a non negative r.v. T, if $\exists b: Pr[T>b]=0$ then
> $$Pr[T\geq t] \geq \frac{\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[T] -t+1}{b-t+1}\qquad \forall t \in \{1,...,b-1\}$$

It should derive somehow from the following corollary of Markov's lemma:

> Given a non negative r.v. T, if $\exists b: Pr[T>b]=0$ then
> $$Pr[T\geq t] \geq \frac{\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[T] -t}{b-t}\qquad \forall t \in \{1,...,b-1\}$$

I've tried to do a variable substitution but it doesn't work.

I've tried to proof by contradiction but without success.

Anyone can help me, please?

---

### Proof

I've found an elegant proof based on @Graf Zahl's idea of breaking summations.
We have
$$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[T] = \sum_{s=1}^{t-1}P[T\geq s] + \sum_{s=t}^{b}P[T\geq s]$$
$$\leq (t-1)P[T\geq 1] + (b-t+1)P[T \geq t]$$
$$\leq (t-1)+ (b-t+1)P[T \geq t]$$
$$\implies P[T \geq t]\geq \frac{\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[T] -t+1}{b-t+1}$$

---

### <s>Proof (substitution)</s>

Let $\hat t = t-1$ then
$$\frac{\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[T] -t+1}{b-t+1} = \frac{\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[T] -\hat t}{b-\hat t} \leq Pr[T\geq \hat t] \leq Pr[T\geq \hat t-1]$$

It could work if we have $\hat t=t+1$...

---

### <s>Proof (contradiction)</s>

Assume that there exists some $t \in \{1,...,b-1\}$ such that the inequality is not satisfied. Then
$$Pr[T\geq t] < \frac{\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[T] -t+1}{b-t+1} \leq Pr[T\geq t-1] \qquad (OK)$$
I don't know how to proceed further here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that $T$ takes values in $\{0,1,\dots,b\}$. Then
$$ E[T]=\sum_{s=1}^bsP(T=s)=\sum_{s=1}^{t-1}sP(T=s)+\sum_{s=t}^bsP(T=s)\\
\leq (t-1)\sum_{s=0}^{t-1}P(T=s)+\sum_{s=t}^{b}(t-1)P(T=s)+\sum_{s=t}^{b}(s-(t-1))P(T=s)\\
=(t-1)\sum_{s=0}^bP(T=s)+\sum_{s=t}^{b}(s-(t-1))P(T=s)\\
\leq(t-1)+(b-(t-1))\sum_{s=t}^bP(T=s)\\
=(t-1)+(b-(t-1))P(T\geq s)
$$
which gives you exactly your desired inequality.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: In my updated question I provided a more elagant proof based on this idea :)

Comment: @EnricoR. Yep, that's a nice shortcut.